# WriteFile lpNumberOfBytesWritten less than nNumberOfBytesToWrite

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

When calling `WriteFile` can the returned `lpNumberOfBytesWritten` ever be less than `nNumberOfBytesToWrite` in synchronous write mode where an error has not occured (return is `TRUE`)? Writing is done to a proper file (not a socket, pipe, or other special handle). `lpOverlapped` is not used.

It is not entirely clear from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

The documentation states:

> The WriteFile function returns when
>   one of the following conditions occur:
>
> - The number of bytes requested is written.
> - A read operation releases buffer space on the read end of the pipe (if
>     the write was blocked). For more
>     information, see the Pipes section.
> - An asynchronous handle is being used and the write is occurring
>     asynchronously.
> - An error occurs.

Only the first one of these meets your criteria so the answer is that the documentation is clear `*lpNumberOfBytesWritten` is always equal to `nNumberOfBytesToWrite` when the function returns when called as you specify.

Comment: So what's the purpose of the lpNumberOfBytesWritten?  It seems useless.